# how to get images in bootstrap carousel dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, html, loops, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap carousel. I have two column in each row. I want my images to come from database through php.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/full-slider.css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

         <?php 
            $query = mysql_query("select * from slides");
            while($row = mysql_fetcj_array($query)){
                $slides = $row['image'];
            ?>

            <div class="item active">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> <img src="<?php echo $slides ?>" alt=""/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption</div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""/>
                     <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption</div>
                   </div>

                 </div>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>


        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that I have my first div class (item active), and others are just item. When I applied my PHP every div gets class (item active) how I applied loop in PHP that my html did not disturb and my slider run accurately.

Comment: Could you share the code with your own php implemented so we could point the mistake to you? Because right now it's more like asking us to do it from scratch.

Comment: `mysql_fetcj_array` that's a typo and a major one at that, where you didn't check for errors.

Comment: its written by mistake my php is running fine. I just have the issue of my class that is item active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way to do it or not..but what i will suggest is to not to apply the active class in the loop.. Let the DOM load and then apply it to the first index of class using JS(or Jquery).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("item")[0].addClass("active");
})
```

OR you can just add an if in the PHP code for the first index

```
if(index==0){
  echo "<p class='item active'></p>";
}else{  
 echo "<p class='item'></p>";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so will answer, sorry.

Where is your PHP? Hard to figure out whats wrong with it without seeing it..

EDIT: Your code only has one item defined. It's surprising the carousel even works. You need to close the div

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Check for first iteration:

```
<?php
    $isFirst = true;

    while (image loop) {

        // echoing image start...
        echo "<img ";

        // echoing stuff
        if ($isFirst) { 
            echo "class='active'"; 
        }

        // echoing the end of image
        echo " />";

        $isFirst = false;
    }
?>
```